# Set font for all textViews in activity?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, typeface

Is it possible to set the font for all the TextViews in a activity? I can set the font for a single textView by using:

```
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf"); 
    tv.setTypeface(face);
```

But I would like to change all the textViews at once, instead of setting it manually for every textView, any info would be appreciated!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Solution1:: Just call these method by passing parent view as argument.

```
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
         }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
 }
 }
```

Solution2::  you can subclass the TextView class with your custom font and use it instead of textview.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Both solutions work, in fact.
But the first is really heavy and every time you add a TextView on a Layout, you must recall the method...
The second is the best, but it implies a whole refactoring of the project (note that if the project is not huge, it can take a few minutes...

Comment: @ChristopheCVB exactly but i have two solution and him decide what he wanna to do and the second is best solution

Comment: Yes, of course, I really agree with you. Thanks for these solutions !

Comment: Improvement to method 1 would be to create the Typeface once (Typeface.createFromAsset) and save it as a field in the class, instead of creating it for each TextView.

Comment: is it good to use this library http://mycode.restservices.org/2013/10/01/excellent-library-for-custom-fonts-in-android/ in terms of performance and all?

Comment: Works with textviews, but webView(not work) or spinners(not work) ?

Comment: That "catch all" is bad

Comment: How is the performance when calling `Typeface.createFromAsset` so often? I mean when i have ~20 TextViews in an activity. Will it be still ok?

Comment: How will I use it if I set my view in the layout as textView before ?

Answer (score 8):

The one from my personal collection:

```
private void setFontForContainer(ViewGroup contentLayout) {
    for (int i=0; i < contentLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = contentLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof TextView)
            ((TextView)view).setTypeface(yourFont);
        else if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            setFontForContainer((ViewGroup) view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a more general programatic solution, I created a static class that can be used to set the Typeface of an entire view (Activity UI). Note that I am working with Mono (C#) but you can implement it easily using Java.

You can pass this class a layout or a specific view that you want to customize. If you want to be super efficient you could implement it using the Singleton pattern.

```
public static class AndroidTypefaceUtility 
{
    static AndroidTypefaceUtility()
    {
    }
    //Refer to the code block beneath this one, to see how to create a typeface.
    public static void SetTypefaceOfView(View view, Typeface customTypeface)
    {
    if (customTypeface != null && view != null)
    {
            try
            {
                if (view is TextView)
                    (view as TextView).Typeface = customTypeface;
                else if (view is Button)
                    (view as Button).Typeface = customTypeface;
                else if (view is EditText)
                    (view as EditText).Typeface = customTypeface;
                else if (view is ViewGroup)
                    SetTypefaceOfViewGroup((view as ViewGroup), customTypeface);
                else
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility: {0} is type of {1} and does not have a typeface property", view.Id, typeof(View));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility threw:\n{0}\n{1}", ex.GetType(), ex.StackTrace);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility: customTypeface / view parameter should not be null");
            }
        }

        public static void SetTypefaceOfViewGroup(ViewGroup layout, Typeface customTypeface)
        {
            if (customTypeface != null && layout != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < layout.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    SetTypefaceOfView(layout.GetChildAt(i), customTypeface);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("AndroidTypefaceUtility: customTypeface / layout parameter should not be null");
            }
        }

    }
```

In your activity you will need to create a Typeface object. I create mine in the OnCreate() using a .ttf file placed in my Resources/Assets/ directory. Make sure that the file is marked as an Android Asset in its' properties.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{               
    ...
    LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.signInView_LinearLayout);
    Typeface allerTypeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(base.Assets,"Aller_Rg.ttf");
    AndroidTypefaceUtility.SetTypefaceOfViewGroup(rootLayout, allerTypeface);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm for me in Xamarin, THANKS!

Comment: p.s. EditText and Button both extend TextView, so you don't need to check for them explicitly

Comment: Does this work for views that haven't been created yet?

Answer (score 2):

**Best answers**

**1. Setting custom font for one textView**

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Fonts/FontName.ttf");
textView.setTypeface (typeface);
```

---

**2. Setting custom font for all textViews**

Create a JavaClass like below

```
public class CustomFont extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    public CustomFont(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/FontName.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

And in your xml page

```
<packageName.javaClassName>

...

/>
```

=>

```
    <com.mahdi.hossaini.app1.CustomFont
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="KEEP IT SIMPLE"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending Agarwal's answer... you can set regular, bold, italic, etc by switching the style of your TextView.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextViewAsap extends TextView {

    public TextViewAsap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public TextViewAsap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TextViewAsap(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.DEFAULT;

            switch (getTypeface().getStyle()) {
                case Typeface.BOLD:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Fonts/Asap-Bold.ttf");
                    break;

                case Typeface.ITALIC:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Fonts/Asap-Italic.ttf");
                    break;

                case Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Fonts/Asap-Italic.ttf");
                    break;

                default:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Fonts/Asap-Regular.ttf");
                    break;
            }

            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

You can create your Assets folder like this:
[image: Create Assets]

And your Assets folder should look like this:

[image]

Finally your TextView in xml should be a view of type TextViewAsap. Now it can use any style you coded...

```
<com.example.project.TextViewAsap
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Example Text"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Calligraphy` library which is available here:
[Android Calligraphy Library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Answer (score 0):

### example of more "generic" way with use of reflection:

** it's presenting a idea of involving viewgroup children's method setTextSize(int,float) but you can adopt it as in the case of your question to setTypeFace()

```
 /**
 * change text size of view group children for given class
 * @param v - view group ( for example Layout/widget)
 * @param clazz  - class to override ( for example EditText, TextView )
 * @param newSize - new font size
 */
public static void overrideTextSize(final View v, Class<?> clazz, float newSize) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideTextSize(child, clazz, newSize);
            }
        } else if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass())) {
            /** create array for params */
            Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class[2];
            /** set param array */
            paramTypes[0] = int.class;  // unit
            paramTypes[1] = float.class; // size
            /** get method for given name and parameters list */
            Method method = v.getClass().getMethod("setTextSize",paramTypes);
            /** create array for arguments */
            Object arglist[] = new Object[2];
            /** set arguments array */
            arglist[0] = TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP;
            arglist[1] = newSize;
            /** invoke method with arguments */
            method.invoke(v,arglist);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**CAUTION:**

using reflection should be very careful. Reflection class it's very "**exceptional**"

- for example, you should check for the presence of annotations to prevent different kinds of problems. In the case of method SetTextSize () It is desirable to check the annotations *android.view.RemotableViewMethod*

Answer (score 0):

You can use style inheritance.

Have every one of your TextViews in the activity declare a style via `android:textAppearence`, instead of manually `android:typeface`.

Then, have each one's style inherit the activity style, like so:

```
<TextView ...
      android:textAppearance="@style/item_name"/>
<TextView ...
      android:textAppearance="@style/item_details"/>
```

in style.xml:

```
<style name="ActivityStyle">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font</item>
</style>
<style name="item_name" parent="ActivityStyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
<style name="item_details" parent="ActivityStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```