# Change font for EditText in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, typeface

Is there any way to change the font for a EditText in Android? I want it to match the font's I set for all my textViews.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766716/set-font-for-all-textviews-in-activity/10766791#10766791

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41275113/4729523)! It allows you use multiple fonts and using XML.

Comment: You can now specify custom fonts right from the XML in android studio 3.0 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
 editText.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
```

As like as for TextView.

```
 <TextView
  ...
     android:typeface="serif"
  ... />
```

Edit: Above is the XML

Comment: I didn't realize it was that simple! Thank you!

Comment: Or you can set android:typeface attribute in the xml layout. Some people think that is even simpler.

Answer (score 27):

Solution1:: Just call these method by passing parent view as argument.

```
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
         }
        } else if (v instanceof EditText) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
 }
}
```

Solution2:: you can subclass the TextView class with your custom font and use it instead of textview.

```
public class MyEditView extends EditText{

    public MyEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyEditView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 11):

Create a *fonts* folder on *assets* folder and put your .ttf font file, then into onCreate() function write:

```
EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.insert_yors_edit_text_layout);
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/yours_font.ttf"); 
editText.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create **font** folder under res directory in last version Android studio 3 .Then copy and past it you'r font to **font** folder. Now just add `fontFamily` to **EditText** tag xml.

like below.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/subject"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerShare"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ritaric"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="Subject"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/colors_textview_size" />
```

We use `android:fontFamily="@font/ritaric"` for apply font on EditText.

Answer (score 1):

```
void setFont(Context context, ViewGroup vg)
        {
          final String FONT_NAME = "lato_bold.ttf";
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                    View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
                    if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
                        setFont(context, (ViewGroup) v);
                    else if (v instanceof TextView)
                        {
                            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_NAME ));
                        }
                    else if (v instanceof EditText)
                        {
                            ((EditText) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_NAME ));
                        }
                    else if (v instanceof Button)
                        {
                            ((Button) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_NAME ));
                        }
                    else if (v instanceof CheckBox)
                        {
                            ((CheckBox) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_NAME ));
                        }
                    else if (v instanceof RadioButton)
                        {
                            ((RadioButton) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_NAME ));
                        }
                }
        }
```

In your Activity or Fragment , get the main layout

```
Inflater inflater = (Inflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//For Activity
//Inflater inflater = (Inflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
//For Activity
//View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_fragment, null, false);
if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
    {
      setFont(getActivity(), (ViewGroup) v);
      //For Activity
     //setFont(this, (ViewGroup) v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## First Method

use this code in your java class

```
    EditText et_brand=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_brand);
    et_brand.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Aspergit Bold.ttf")); 
    //Aspergit Bold.ttf is Font style name of text
```

### Second Method

1. Create a new java class and it as u want

   ```
   public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

   public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
   {
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   init();
   }

   public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   init();
   }

   public CustomTextView(Context context) {
   super(context);
   init();
   }

   private void init() {
      Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), 
   "Aspergit Bold.ttf");
   setTypeface(tf);
   }
   }
   ```
2. Use it in your Xml file

   ```
                 <YourPackageNAme.CustomEditText
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@null"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code in your java file**
Which type you want you can add like NORMAL, ITALIC, BOLD, BOLD_ITALIC.

edittext.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);

Answer (score 0):

lil late but, 
Simple way

```
 mEditTextMobileNumber.setTextSize(16.0f);
```

if you want to change font while typing :

```
   // Change text size when started entering number
    mEditTextMobileNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s == null || String.valueOf(s).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                mEditTextMobileNumber.setTextSize(12.0f);
            } else {
                mEditTextMobileNumber.setTextSize(20.0f);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```