# How to apply a specific font to EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am new to android development, I need to implement Rich text Editor in my Application. So i googled and found some solutions. I am using this solution:

http://code.google.com/p/android-richtexteditor/source/browse/?r=4#svn/trunk/src/net/sgoliver

It supports the Bold, Italic and Underline in it. Now I want to change the font-style of selected text in EditText, How do i do that?

I know how to set the [font-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766943/change-font-for-edittext-in-android) for all the text in EditText. Suggestions will be appriciated!

Comment: you can store the font you want to use in assets folder and set it using typeface.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the font files (*.ttf) to the assets folder of your application.

Consider I have copied the font file "verdana.TTF" to the assets folder, then the following code will set the font to verdana

```
EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Typeface tf =   Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"verdana.TTF");
et.setTypeface(tf);
```

Hope you got the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF); as like as TextView.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tf =   Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Comic.ttf");
EditText et =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
et.setTypeface(tf);
```

you can place ttf file in assets and set font style here

Answer (score 0):

try this code..create font folder like this assets/font and put your font file in it..

```
 edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset( this.getAssets(), "font/YOURFONT.otf");

 edittxt.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```