# custom typeface for all Indian languages with Facebook api

Tags: android, fonts

my android application uses facebook api to read latest FB  status update of the user.but some of them are written in local languages like Hindi,Malayalam,Tamil (eg: ശിഖര്‍ ധവാന്‍ , രോഹിത് ശര്‍മ, വിരാട് കോലി, സുരേഷ് റെയ്‌ന, അജിങ്ക്യ രഹാനെ,सभी को सुप्रभात)etc.how to make all these text readable while displaying in a textview?

Comment: You can use the textView.setText(VariableName)

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the default Android font ([Roboto](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) since ICS) doesn't include Hindi, Malayalam and Tamil. At least I'm not able to find evidence that it does. Judging from [this post](http://got-code.blogspot.se/2012/08/jellybean-41-fixing-malayalam-rendering.html) Jellybean ships with a font with support for Malayalam (and possibly others). Still, you need to explicitly specify the use of this font if you wish the text to render properly in a textview or similar. To set a specific TypeFace you can use [TextView.setTypeface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29). I would suggest that you bundle the font mentioned in the link above in your assets folder and load it like this:

```
TypeFace tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "AnjaliNewLipi-light.ttf")
```

You might want to look into [caching the TypeFace to prevent memory leaks](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904) on older Android versions. Resuse [this class](https://github.com/britzl/androidutils/blob/master/androidutils-lib/src/se/springworks/android/utils/font/FontCache.java) if you wish.

Also, for advanced use, you can make your TextViews, Buttons etc styleable via XML by following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648190/how-to-set-a-particular-font-for-a-button-text-in-android/16648457#16648457).