# How to set custom fonts on EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to implement a custom typeface on an `EditText`. Does anyone have a better approach as opposed to what I'm currently doing?

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
edittext.setTypeface(myFont);
```

Because I have lots of `EditText`s...

Comment: what your problem then

Answer (score 20):

```
public class CEditText extends EditText {


    private Context context;
    private AttributeSet attrs;
    private int defStyle;

    public CEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
        init();
    } 

     public CEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          this.context=context;
          this.attrs=attrs;
          init();
     }

    public CEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyle);
          this.context=context;
          this.attrs=attrs;
          this.defStyle=defStyle;
          init();
    }

    private void init() {
          Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
          this.setTypeface(font);
    }
    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
        super.setTypeface(tf, style);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
        tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
        super.setTypeface(tf);
    }
```

call this class in XML as follows

```
<yourpackagename.CEditText  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
</yourpackagename.CEditText>
```

Comment: whaaaa! That's great! But I wonder @SainathPatwarykarnate.... how to make each word defined each style of that edittext?

Comment: if you really want each and every word should have different style of single edit text , that always depends on the word length .. and many other things , so better you maintain one parametrize method which changes the style based on the different values of the method as of now i don't have any defined solution for that

Comment: for the concept / the flow I understand what you're saying @SainathPatwarykarnate.... yes, I think we better get into the code to make it real :D

Comment: can u pls elaborate what do you mean

Answer (score 6):

Create a new class that extends `EditText` like

```
public class CustomEditTextNormal extends EditText
{

  public CustomEditTextNormal(Context context)
  {
      super(context);
      init(context);
  }

  public CustomEditTextNormal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
  }

  public CustomEditTextNormal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
  }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

  public void init(Context context)
  {
    try
    {
        Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");

        setTypeface(mSearchAndSend.HelveticaLight);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogError(e);
    }
  }
}
```

and include it on your XML like

```
<com.package.name.CustomEditText/>
```

Comment: Don't catch Exception though

Answer (score 0):

How about create a new class that inherits EditText and sets the typeface you want and then instantiate the new class in the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class which inherits from `EditText`, and then override the `public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)` method and add your own font.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one method in Common class Like,

```
public void setExternalFonts(EdiText tv) {
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/myfont.ttf");
  tv.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

Now call this method as

```
yourClassName.setExternalFonts(yourEditText);
```

Comment: I tried this but there is some issue while setting path. I have set my path like this
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "/assets/roboto_regular.ttf"); can you let me know where I am wrong ?

Comment: If it has been put only in assets folder then just change `/assets/roboto_regular.ttf` to `roboto_regular.ttf`. Show your fonts structure.

Comment: Seems like the fonts are not changing, they are as it is.what might be the issue ? @Piyush

Comment: src>main>assets>roboto_regular.ttf this kind of structure is there.

Comment: Are you doing it programmatically ?

Comment: I am able to set the text to the edittext but I want to set it to the hint of the edittext , can you help me with that ?

Comment: I need to put custom fonts on hint not the hint.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new class which inherits from EditText, and then override the public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) method and add your own font.

And use in your activity like this
FontLoader.setQuickSandTypeface(YourEditText) in your activity

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
public void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "roboto_thin.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also useful for Buttons, TextViews.. whatever!

```
<your.namespace.app.FontEditText
     app:font="montserrat"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

How is possible? This way!

```
public class FontEditText extends EditText {

public FontEditText(Context context) {
    this( context, null );
}

public FontEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this( context, attrs, 0 );
    init( context, attrs );
}

public FontEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super( context, attrs, defStyle );
    init( context, attrs );
}

public FontEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super( context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes );
    init( context, attrs );
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes( attrs, R.styleable.Fonts );

    if ( ta != null ) {
        String fontAsset = ta.getString( R.styleable.Fonts_font );
        if ( !StringUtils.isEmpty( fontAsset ) ) {
            int type = Integer.parseInt( fontAsset );

            Typeface typeFace = FontManager.getInstance( context ).getByType( type );
            ta.recycle();
            super.setTypeface( typeFace );
        }
    }
}

}

public class FontManager {

private static FontManager Instance;

private Context context;

private Typeface robotoCondensedBold;
private Typeface robotoCondensed;
private Typeface robotoLight;
private Typeface kronica;
private Typeface montserrat;
private Typeface montserratLight;
private Typeface keepCalmMedium;

private FontManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.robotoCondensedBold = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf" );
    this.robotoCondensed = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf" );
    this.robotoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf" );
    this.kronica = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/kronika.ttf" );
    this.montserrat = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf" );
    this.montserratLight = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf" );
    this.keepCalmMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset( context.getAssets(), "fonts/KeepCalmMedium.ttf" );
}

public synchronized static FontManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if ( Instance == null )
        Instance = new FontManager( context );

    return Instance;
}

public Typeface getByType(int type) {
    switch ( type ) {
        case 0:
            return FontManager.getInstance( context ).getRobotoCondensedBold();
        case 1:
            return FontManager.getInstance( context ).getRobotoLight();
        case 2:
            return FontManager.getInstance( context ).getKronica();
        case 3:
            return FontManager.getInstance( context ).getRobotoCondensed();
        case 4:
            return FontManager.getInstance( context ).getMontserrat();
        case 5:
            return FontManager.getInstance( context ).getMontserratLight();
        case 6:
            return FontManager.getInstance( context ).getKeepCalmMedium();
        default:
            return Typeface.DEFAULT;
    }
}

public Typeface getRobotoCondensedBold() {
    return robotoCondensedBold;
}

public Typeface getKronica() {
    return kronica;
}

public Typeface getRobotoCondensed() {
    return robotoCondensed;
}

public Typeface getRobotoLight() {
    return robotoLight;
}

public Typeface getMontserrat() {
    return montserrat;
}

public Typeface getMontserratLight() {
    return montserratLight;
}

public Typeface getKeepCalmMedium() {
    return keepCalmMedium;
}
```

In addition, a `font_attrs.xml` in your `res` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Fonts">
        <attr name="font" format="enum">
            <enum name="robotoCondensedBold" value="0"/>
            <enum name="robotoLight" value="1"/>
            <enum name="kronica" value="2"/>
            <enum name="robotoCondensed" value="3"/>
            <enum name="montserrat" value="4"/>
            <enum name="montserratLight" value="5"/>
            <enum name="keepCalmMedium" value="6"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

> Note that you only need to modify the `FontManager` and the `font_attrs.xml` to customize your fonts!