# How to add Custom EditText in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, fonts

My Question is not duplicate of [How to set custom fonts on EditText Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23629122/5505915). My profile is different. I am successfully able to set custom font in edittext & Textview, but I am not able to set my customEditText inside the TextInputLayout.

I am trying to set Custom EditText, TextView  in my project.

Following code works fine,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ....
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtUserID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Now I have customised the Edit Text and adding as follows,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ....
        >

    <com.custom.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtUserID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My CustomEditText's code snipet,

```
private void init(Context context) {
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

When I run this code, It gives me following error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found arial.ttf
      at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:190)
      at com.custom.CustomEditText.init(CustomEditText.java:34)
      at com.custom.CustomEditText.<init>(CustomEditText.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
```

If I use CustomEditText without TextInputLayout then it works fine. My Font is properly added in assets folder which is inside the main folder of project.

Comment: Are you sure you've added `arial.ttf` to the right folder? It needs to go into `/src/main/assets/arial.ttf`

Comment: @oiZo, Yes it is properly added. Please check the last lines of my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629122/how-to-set-custom-fonts-on-edittext-android

Comment: @RohitArya, Yes that's how I set my font.

Comment: I cannot see why you'd get that exception, if you are absolutely sure you've added the resource to that folder.

Comment: @oiZo, Please read my question properly, My problem is different.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `init(Context)` method and running the code again?

Comment: if  I will do it then it will not going to set arial font for EditText.

Comment: @oiZo, Dont know how but, suddenly it started working properly. Now I can see my customised editText inside the TextInputLayout.