# Change typeface in MvxLinearLayout

Tags: mvvmcross

How do I change the typeface for a button in an 'item' template used by MvxLinearLayout?
I am able to change the typeface for a standalone button but not sure how to do it for an item in an MvxLinearLayout.

Comment: Step by step: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16648457/1421015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already answered your question.  Change the type face on the button itself, not the layout.

Comment: I meant loading a custom typeface.

Comment: Look at this example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203694/custom-fonts-in-android

Comment: Thanks, that should do it.