# How to support Arabic Text Font for all devices?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, android-typeface

i create an Android app Activity which contain Arabic Text and i set Typeface on this text like as

```
 Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "trado.ttf");
 textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

but this Typeface not supporting  all deveice's. On Samsun S4 its work correcctly but on Samsung grand it's not work.

Screenshot of Samsung galaxy s4 which show Arabic Text properly

[image]

Screenshot of Samsung grand which can't show Arabic Text properly

[image]

i am attach both screen shot please check it and  tell me,
how i can handle this issue.

Comment: Use RTL Layout and check it

Comment: Not Placement Issu ,i already use RTL layout but not working.

Comment: more information might be helpful - what's not working? did you get any exception on this code line? or on other lines? is the text not showing? or showing gibberish? is it a text you receive from an outer source? (e.g. some web service) or is it hard coded, we really need more info in order to help

Comment: @JawadAli how did you resolved the problem I have same problem in implementing nastaleeq font on URDU language. 
text just got over lapped in textview.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the TypeFace, otherwise [you might risk memory leaks on older handsets](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904). Caching will increase speed as well since it's not super fast to read from assets all the time.

```
public class FontCache {

    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);
        if(tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

I gave a full example on [how to load custom fonts and style textviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648190/how-to-set-a-particular-font-for-a-button-text-in-android/16648457#16648457) as an answer to a similar question. You seem to be doing most of it right, but you should cache the font as recommended above.

[Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) is looks for the font in a pretty specific order, for the most part it's very similar to how the Android framework resolves attributes.

Define your default font using CalligraphyConfig, in your Application class in the #onCreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}
```

Initially i recommended to try the 1st approach, still if you faced the problem then go for 2nd approach (3rd party library)

Hope this will helps

Comment: show Syntax error on 
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(required int value ), tf);

Comment: sorry for unable to help :( let see some one will come up with solution

Comment: now i attach images ,one image show Arabic Text properly in S4 and in Samsung Grand not work properly.
please check it and help me to solving the problem .
@King of Masses

Answer (score 0):

I think create *value-arabic-> strings.xml* and write here your text. It will be help