# Android - What is the best way to use a custom font application wide

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface

I want to use Google's Raleway font in my android app. I have read a lot of blogs and a number of answers on stackOverflow but haven't found the exact answer.

[The best answer i found is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648457/3502919) that explains to create custom TextViews efficiently.

**If i have two use two variations of the font say Raleway-Regular and Raleway-SemiBold, do i have to create two custom TextViews or is there any better way to achieve that ?**

Comment: You can make your own textView

Comment: @KhizarHayat - If i have two use two variations of the font say Raleway-Regular and Raleway-SemiBold, do i have to create two custom TextViews ?

Comment: no use one textview assign it at runtime

Comment: or you may be assign using TypeFace

Comment: A lot of people are recommending [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) . Which of the two methods you recommend ?

Comment: i have not used Calligraphy, i made my own textView and use TypeFace. may be Calligraphy is better option but i have not experienced that library

Answer (score 1):

I have done the task the following way
Download the ttf of that font and then paste it inside the asset folder(you have to create the assets folder inside /src/main/assets)
then change the font the following way:

> Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "condenced.ttf");
>   tv_the.setTypeface(face);

you can download the multiple ttf files and can display the different fonts to different fields.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I want a solution that is application wide, in this case i'll have to set the typeface multiple times that is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library for my project and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to use a custom font is this library:
[Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)