# set Custom Font for navgiation view header

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I created an android studio default navgation view and i put two buttons in nav_header_main.xml (see the picture below)
now i want to set a custom font for the button.
i tried this in MainActivity.java :

```
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    b.setTypeface(font);
```

but it didn't work!!
how can i do this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcIj3.png)

Comment: create custom class extending Button class then use that to create button with xml rather than  default <Button/> !

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16648457/7267105

Comment: Please explain exactly how "it didn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a custom class extending from **Button**.

**Here is an example:**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomFontButton extends Button {

    public CustomFontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomFontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomFontButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(font);
    }

}
```

**Use it from XML:**

```
<com.example.test.CustomFontButton
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:text="Button Text" />
```