# Recyclerview lags on scroll if custom font is used

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

To set a **custom font** I have created a `CutomTextView` by extending `TextView` but the `RecyclerView` lags while scrolling when the `CutomTextView` is used. I have tried using a standard `Textview` and setting the font in the `ViewHolder` but the result is the same.

**CustomTextView.java**

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/hell.ttf"));
    }
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class DashBoardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DashBoardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<PatientList> patientListList;
private Activity activity;

public DashBoardAdapter(List<PatientList> patientListList, Activity activity) {
    this.patientListList = patientListList;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_dashboard_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final PatientList p = patientListList.get(position);
    if(p.getName() != null)
        holder.username.setText(p.getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return patientListList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    @BindView(R.id.patient_username) TextView username;
    private View itemView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);

        // Setting font here when custom textview is not used
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

what could be the reason for the lag?

Comment: because font rendering when recycler view scroll

Comment: Size of the font file you are using?

Comment: @muditsen1234: 36kb

Comment: Look at this link this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648190/how-to-set-a-particular-font-for-a-button-text-in-android/16648457#16648457

Comment: you need to cache Typeface. doesn't need to initialize every time you use it

Comment: @PiyushPatel : yes caching was the solution.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome..! Give some credit man...

Comment: @PiyushPatel : paste it as answer with some explanation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this link this might help
 [How to set a particular font for a button text in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648190/how-to-set-a-particular-font-for-a-button-text-in-android/16648457#16648457)

You need to cache Typeface doesn't need to initialize every time you use Typeface.