# Put a space after transforming the password text into asterisks

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application, I am using the below `passwordTransformationClass` for showing the password in asterisk format. The problem is,  I want a space after each text in the edit text, i.e. a space after every asterisk. But the overridden methods don’t take space except a single asterisk character.

```
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;

        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }

        public char charAt(int index)
        {

            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }

        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }

        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you gone through Editext.addTextChangedListener.

Comment: @HimanshuMori- Let me try that, thank you.

Comment: Do you want spaces just for a visual effect??? In that case use letterSpacing

Comment: Actually letterSpacing not supported.

Comment: @Himanshu Mori- TextChangedListener not working

Comment: okay check mine answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input : <*****>

I hope this is your input in EditTextView and you want to transform the EditTextView text to something like

Output: <* * * * *>

then set some custom EditTextView fonts which have much spacing between characters...

[Change font for EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766943/change-font-for-edittext-in-android)

and if you are going through  **Editext.addTextChangedListener**, we can do it but we have to write down some expensive Logics into it
to handle ***copy, paste, backspace*** and so many other cases .. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please recommend any font with spaces between characters so that I can test it out?@Himanshu Mori

Comment: my designer knows these fonts http://fontzone.net/font-details/oratorstd

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the code from

```
        public char charAt(int index)
        {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
```

to

```
        public string charAt(int index)
        {
            return "* "; // This is the important part
        }
```

Comment: @Tony- tried that. Its showing error there. It doesn't take more than 1 character.

Comment: @AnimeshJena have you tried to take the transformed text and modify it with spaces between asterisks? after you have transformed it to asterisks..then put a space between each asterisk