# Hidden Password dot spacing change in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-typeface

[image: Screenshot of Hidden Password]

> My issue is when you hit show / hide password (eye icon) to display
>   password. The dot spacing for the same password takes more space. Is
>   there any way to fit it in same position at which the text or the
>   password is? I think there is an issue with TypeFace but not fully
>   sure about it.

[image: Screenshot of Show Password]

I tried following this link, its kind of the same thing but its not working. Its either changing my font family or my font style.  [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205916/7505562)

Comment: Extend the ```PasswordTransformationMethod``` class and try to create your own password dots, And set that, with this method ```setTransformationMethod``` of your EditText.

Comment: This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849287/5255963) may help you

Comment: @AliRezaiyan Actually thats not working. Tried it. thats not how i want to do it, changing each character by character :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issues some days ago
for viewing password use this code (this code is in kotlin if you are using java and face any issue comment here I will help in that also).

```
et_pass.transformationMethod = null
```

and for hiding password again use this code

```
et_pass.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod()
```

Comment: thats what i am doing  for show hide password. It works perfect, its just how to maintain the spacing of dots as same as the text written :)

Comment: I am sorry but its not working for me, tried it. It only prevents from going text to next line.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this code below within your password XML UI. This will hide the letters and create dots.

app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"