# Android font text difference

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

I want to use custom font Avenir-Roman in tff format in android, but both on the device and in the preview window of Android Studio it looks totally different from real one.[image] 
I try to use different approaches such as standard fontFamily attribute, set typeface from assets folder, Caligraphy library - all the same effect. What the reason of such distortion and how to fix this?

Comment: You should read [0][this] [0]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760019/font-gets-changed-in-android-studio-preview-but-not-in-the-emulator-device

Comment: The problem is not in implementing stuff but in the completely different font in android devices(preview window) and real font appearance.