# How can I change my app font

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-typeface

I'm developing a notepad application I want to use my custom font and I'm following this code.

```
Typeface barType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"font/CaviarDreams.ttf");
    subject.setTypeface(barType);
```

But, I don't want to use this code because I must write this code for every textview or edittext.
Is there any way to make this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void setFont(final Context context, final View v) {
        try {
            if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
                for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                    overrideFonts(context, child);
                }
            } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica.ttf"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Use this method in utility class and pass parent view as an argument, it will update all textviews with your font

Eg.

```
    View parent = (View)findViewById(R.id.parent);
    Util.setFont(this,parent);
```

Please check this [Set font for all textViews in activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766716/set-font-for-all-textviews-in-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You have to sublcass `TextView`/`EditText` and use your subclass inside the xml

```
private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/CaviarDreams.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
```

and call the `init()` method from the constructor your Custom `TextView`/`EditText`

Comment: Same thing with the doing programmatically!I think maybe I can find easy way to do this in manifest or MainActivity?

Comment: no there is no way to do this thing through xml. Nevertheless you can access all the view in the current hierarchy and apply the typeface. I can show you it if you want but the better solution is to subclass

Comment: OK,if there is no way I will create subclass.

Comment: why are you scared to subclass those classes?

Comment: No,I'm not scared.I just find to best way to do this and I asked you.Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass EditText and in it's constructor set typeface

For ex:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditTextWithFont extends EditText {

    public EditTextWithFont(Context c) {
        super(c);
        init();
    }

    public EditTextWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public EditTextWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface barType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"font/CaviarDreams.ttf");
            setTypeface(barType);
        }
    }
}
```

You can create similar classes for textview and button

Answer (score 0):

Global `Roboto light` for `TextView` and `Button` classes.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

Just select the style you want from list `themes.xml` then create your custom style based on the original. At the end apply the style as the theme of the application.

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```