# How to Use Custom Font into Non-Activity Class in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

This question is very stupid, I just want to know how to use Custom font, in non-Activity class? cause I really don't know how to change font into non-activity class in android, this my case, i have class called :

```
 sma.java
 package com.example.database.search;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.widget.DatePicker;
 import com.example.search.text;
 public class Sma
 {

//primary key
private long id;

private String  nama;
private String alamat;

private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private int telepon;
private String  website;
private String  email;
private String  tgl_berdiri;
private String  deskripsi_keunggulan;
private String tgl_akreditasi;
private String  facebook;
private String  twitter;

@Override
public String toString()
{
   return "ID : "   + id    
   + "\n" +"Nama :" + nama 
   + "\n" + "Alamat :"+ alamat + "\n" + and so on...;
}
}
```

i just want to know how to using custom font into method toString()? can anyone help me? i really know this is a stupid question, but i need a tutorial in this case. and also, if somebody can give me tutorial how to change font into all activity. Thank you for helping me

Comment: You can't, how would you apply a color to a string object, apply the color to the view where your setting this text.

Comment: @jitainsharma i see that, so if i have textView, how can i change the font in this class?

Comment: To the EditText: ` editText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Roboto-Regular.ttf"));` this is the font file saved under the assets folder. Same for TextView.

Comment: @jitainsharma: okay i get it, and my last question do you know tutorial for change font in all activity in android?

Comment: Make a style and apply to all by code or in layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i just want to know how to using custom font into method toString()?

That is not possible. A `String` does not have a font. Something that *uses* a `String`, like a `TextView`, may use a font.

Comment: okay, but if i have textView in this class, how can i change the font? can u give me an example?

Comment: @ndr_sd: As noted in the question's comments, use `setTypeface()`. To apply a custom font to an entire activity, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766716/set-font-for-all-textviews-in-activity