# Change Button text font using typeface

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the font of all my button in `onCreate()` method
there is a way to do that ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Typeface buttontypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Calculator.ttf");
    // get just buttons ids
}
```

If I use `findViewById` I will get the id for a single button , I want a fast way to get all button ids and then change their font.
ex I have : `button1, button_a, buttonout` ...

Comment: if i have like 10 buttons then i will put findViewById for each single button, i want a fast way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a a simple method like this

```
private void typefaces(int... args){
    Typeface buttontypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Calculator.ttf");
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        ((Button) findViewById(args[i])).setTypeface(buttontypeface);
    }
}
```

and then call it in `onCreate`

```
typefaces(R.id.button, R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3);
```

where `R.id.button, R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3` are the ids from 4 Buttons. You can add as many as you want

Answer (score 0):

It may help you!

```
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Typeface face8 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "MyFont.ttf");
    button.setTypeface(face8);
```

Comment: This code will change the font of the button1 only, i want to change the font off all my button , i dont want to do this operation like 10 times

Comment: while searching for that you can copy and paste ten times Dude! :-P

Comment: lol i just belive their is a easy way to that without copy and past like 10 times :p

Answer (score 0):

This question: [Set font for all textViews in activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766716/set-font-for-all-textviews-in-activity) shows how to achieve this for `TextView`s.

If you want to do the same thing for buttons, use this code:

```
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
try {
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
            overrideFonts(context, child);
     }
    } else if (v instanceof Button ) {
        ((Button) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

All credits go to Agarwal Shankar for this code

As for the parameters: for `context` you probably want to use `this` and for `v` you want to use the parent `View`, which is typically the upper `Layout` attribute (`LinearLayout` or whatever you're using)

Comment: this maybe will works , but i want to take the Viewgroup on onCreate() method not on a method that i need to create it  , can i do that ?

Comment: Sure! Just paste the above method anywhere in the Activity class and then call this method from `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

First get all buttons in your layout, then change the typeface of everyone, let's say that viewGroup is your root View (could be RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc...).

```
int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
      for (int i = 0; i< count; i++){
          if(viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button){
              //do whatever you want here
          }
      }
```

you can get the root View by giving it an if in the xml file.

Comment: getChildAt(i) cannot be referenced from a static context , i cannot use getChildAt(i) on ViewGroup

Comment: no, use getChildAt(i) on the instance that you're working with, not on the name of the class