# Q: Android - Setting Font Color of entire Activity Programmatically with NO XML

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, colors

Unfortunately the 'default' color for the text on all of the default generated slides for the AppIntro Library is White - which in my case, simply doesnt show up very well..

Is it possible to programmatically set the Text Color for the entire current Activity, WITHOUT using any xml/theme/style files?

I'm specifically looking to do this purely programmatically -- NO XML..

...Similar to the way we can define the color of the NavBar, ActionBar, StatusBar, Activity Background, etc. etc.. Surely there must be a way to set the color of all the Text for an entire Activity all at once (without using xml)..?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The principal approach for this would be to find all the widgets that you want to change, then changing them individually. An activity has no idea what text there is.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are absolutely correct.. But unfortunately, I am using an intro/slides Library called AppIntro, which dynamically creates slides for me (which I can manipulate to an extent), but I'm unsure of how to identify the Title and Description Text ID's for all 5 of my slides (which, again, were created dynamically using a library).. Is there a way to programmatically GET the names of all these textviews? If so, it would be a huge help.. Otherwise, I was assuming there would be a simple programmatic way to "get" the activity, and then "set" the text color for it as a whole.. But :\

Comment: "Is there a way to programmatically GET the names of all these textviews?" -- you can't get the names very readily. You can scan through all the views and look for those that are `instanceof TextView`. The approaches that you see for [recursively setting the typeface on all `TextView` widgets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10766716/115145) could be adapted. I have no idea if this library is using `TextView`, though, versus `WebView`, drawing text directly on a `Canvas`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Define your stye and then apply it to the application/activity in manifest.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android)

Comment: Check THIS Question.. I'm clearly asking for a way to do it WITHOUT applying an external style/theme from an xml (which is what you're suggesting).. I am using an Intro/slide Library called AppIntro, which allows me to dynamically create slides (and manipulate them to an extent) but unfortunately I dont know how to identify the Title and Description text for each of my 5 slides in order to do it programmatically.. This is why I am asking for a way to apply a text-color to an entire activity programmatically..