# setting custom font to all my textviews

Tags: java, android

I have this piece of code that I copied from [set-font-for-all-textviews-in-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766716/set-font-for-all-textviews-in-activity). My problem is how to call this method from `onCreate`?

Trying `overrideFonts();`

Code:

```
public void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: wats the issue then?

Comment: You can call it after binding your views

Comment: You need to make a custom textview with the font
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477393/6577752

Comment: @ShivamOberoi my issue is calling the method from on create. As in what parameters do you pass to it Because am doing overrideFonts (); and its not working

Comment: @nullvoid I do not want to do that because I have many views and that would mean going one by one. Instead I want to do bulk.

Comment: Using find and replace is not very difficult. Setting custom font on this much view on initialization, may result in some lag.

Comment: Activity is Context, so you can use "this" for the first parameter. findViewById(android.R.id.content) will be the second one.

Comment: @Grisha thanks so much!!! works like a charm. I did this: overrideFonts(this, findViewById(android.R.id.content));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity is Context, so you can use "this" for the first parameter. findViewById(android.R.id.content) will be the second one.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks so much.